# Does Little Little Snitch 4 block connections during login?

Tags: network, login, internet, firewall, login-items

I have been using Little Snitch for some time now.

I think the version I've started to use the program with, was 3.5.

Anyway, I remember seeing notifications from Little Snitch about connection attempts during login, and then these appeared as 'Suggested rules' in the configuration.

Recently I had to reinstall OS and all the programs on my Mac mini.

I have installed the latest Little Snitch (4.4.3 that is), but after reboot I have not seen notification about connection attempts during login, nor was there a 'Suggested rules' section in the configuration.

In [release notes for Little Snitch 3.*](https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/releasenotes3.html), it is mentioned (*bold is mine*):

> Little Snitch offers rule suggestions based on Silent Mode
>   connections, former, already expired temporary rules, **login
>   connections** and more.

Though, no mention of login connections in [release notes for Little Snitch 4.*](https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/releasenotes.html). I have found an [old thread on official forum](https://forums.obdev.at/viewtopic.php?t=9620), but again - it is about Little Snitch 3.*

The question is:

- Does Little Snitch 4.* 'inherit' the functionality of blocking connections during login from it's predecessor (i.e. Little Snitch 3.*)?

  - If yes, does it have to be enabled in any special way?

---

P.S.: I do realize that this question would be more appropriate at the [official forum of the Little Snitch developers](https://forums.obdev.at/index.php), [but registration there is closed](https://forums.obdev.at/ucp.php?mode=register) (for like a year now).

Comment: You could also just use the contact form on their website :-)

Comment: @nohillside, striving for a public answer here (so that anybody like me could then just land here from the search engine)

Comment: Instead of putting the question on hold, let me just explain the problems we tend to have with basic customer support questions: The functionality you are looking for may still be there and work for most people just out of the box. Answers which say "it works for me" won't help you though, and figuring out in detail *why* it doesn't work for you may require some back and forth with somebody who has experience in solving these kind of issues.

Comment: But maybe I'm overthinking things, let's see whether somebody *has* an answer. Or you could reach out to support nevertheless and then post the answer you get from them :-)

Comment: See also https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2509/9058 for some more details on this.

Comment: Please **also** [contact Objective Development](https://obdev.at/support/index.html?product=LS) and let them know about this question. It gives the developer a chance to respond publicly and to understand where their documentation or support can be improved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Little Snitch itself…

> ## Login Connections
>
> While no user is logged in or a login is in progress, Little Snitch
> cannot display Connection Alerts. It therefore creates suggestions for
> all connection attempts that occur during that time.
>
> See the Little Snitch Help, chapter [Rule suggestions](https://help.obdev.at/littlesnitch/#/lsc-suggestions) for more
> information.

[image]

& detail from just the first entry in that table…

> On 27 10 2019, ARDAgent tried to establish a connection to
> 100.102.5.131. The request was denied automatically during login.

So, yes, it will block attempts by default until you edit the suggestions into actual approved rules.