# Can system interact with internet without being logged in?

Tags: macos, network, wifi, login, internet

**Can system interact with internet without being logged in?**

When user starts the system and login page appears, it seems to automatically connect to the WiFi. Now, can system interact with internet (send/receive data and apply in system) without being logged in but when user is waiting for entering password on the login screen? By system I meant any system app, services, utility with permission granted.

Comment: Sure, any background process already running can access the Internet. Which specific problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: @nohillside could you please share any evidence/ research works or whitepaper for this feasibility. I need it for one of my project works to convince my manager.

Comment: It‘s basically how Unix/macOS works. To verify watch the traffic at the router or monitor your network from another computer

Comment: macOS at least accesses a network time server during startup (should be verifiable in one of the boot scripts in /etc), it probably does even more than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

A simple example is Find My. macOS can receive instructions from Find My to lock or erase a Mac before any user has logged in. This requires macOS to make network requests before login.

To determine what is making connections on your Mac before login, you can use Little Snitch. Create a rule to ask for any connection, then monitor the ‘login connections’ list (see [Does Little Little Snitch 4 block connections during login?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/383088/37797)).